# Laravel FormRequest validation gets User model and sometimes directly the name

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I am using Laravel 8 and validate my requests with the [form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation). However, I have a strange problem. Before I am going to describe my problem I will paste my routes and my validation class here:

routes:

```
Route::post('users', ['as' => 'user.search', 'uses' => 'UserController@indexSearch']);

Route::post('user/name', ['as' => 'user.name.exists', 'uses' => 'UserController@nameExists']);

Route::post('user/email', ['as' => 'user.email.exists', 'uses' => 'UserController@emailExists']);

Route::post('user/email/check', ['as' => 'user.email.check', 'uses' => 'UserController@emailCheck']);

Route::get('user/{user:name}', ['as' => 'user.show', 'uses' => 'UserController@show']);

Route::get('user/{user:name}/einstellungen', ['as' => 'user.settings', 'uses' => 'UserController@showSettings']);

Route::get('user/{user:name}/produkte', ['as' => 'user.products', 'uses' => 'UserController@userProducts']);

Route::post('user/{user:name}/produkte', ['as' => 'user.products.post', 'uses' => 'UserController@userProducts']);

Route::get('user/{user:name}/saved/produkte', ['as' => 'user.marked.products', 'uses' => 'UserController@userMarkedProducts']);

Route::post('user/{user:name}/saved/produkte', ['as' => 'user.marked.products.post', 'uses' => 'UserController@userMarkedProducts']);

Route::post('user/{user:name}/avatar/upload', ['as' => 'user.avatar.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);

Route::post('user/{user:name}/avatar/valid', ['as' => 'user.avatar.valid', 'uses' => 'UserController@validAvatar']);

Route::post('user/{user:name}/avatar/löschen', ['as' => 'user.avatar.delete', 'uses' => 'UserController@deleteAvatar']);

Route::post('user/{user:name}/update/password', ['as' => 'user.password.change', 'uses' => 'UserController@updatePassword']);

Route::post('user/{user:name}/validate/password', ['as' => 'user.password.validate', 'uses' => 'UserController@validatePassword']);
```

This is my `FormRequest` validation which checks if the user is authorized to perform this request and if the given data are valid. As you can see, I check if the `Auth::user()->name` is the same as the requested user (`$this->user->name`) to change the image. Because only the owner of his profile image should be allowed to change is profile image.

```
class UserAvatarUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        dump(array('auth' => Auth::user()->name, 'requested' => $this->user));     

        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->name == $this->user->name){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'avatar' => [
                'required',
                'image',
                'max:5000',
                'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
                Rule::dimensions()->minWidth(200)->minHeight(200)->ratio(1)
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

Now I will come to the problem. As you can see I have several routes for my user and there is one route called `user.avatar.valid` and another route called `user.avatar.update`.

Both routes, `user.avatar.valid` and `user.avatar.update` are using the `FormRequest` validation class I have pasted above. Basically `user.avatar.valid` is being called before the user submits the form to check if the uploaded image is valid. I know, I also could do this in one request but that's not possible because I am using `vee-validate` for Vuejs to validate if the form is valid.

However, thats not the probleme here. The problem is that when calling the `user.avatar.valid` route my dump echos for the key `requested` the `name` of the requested user. But, when performing a request for `user.avatar.update` I don't get the `name` of the user but rather the user `object` which contains the `id`, `name`, `email` and so on.

But exactly this is the point... when trying to call `user.avatar.update` I get a `403` error (forbidden) because `$this->user` is not equal to `Auth::user()->name`. Obviously it is not the same when I compare a `string` (name) to the user `object`.

However, when calling `user.avatar.valid` it passes because here I get the `name` when calling `$this->user` and not the user `object`.

But why is that?

When I change `$this->user` to `$this->user->name` I get the actual name for the user when calling the `user.avatar.update` route but on the other side I get a `500` error when calling the `user.avatar.valid` route because it says `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`...

Does anybody has an idea where the problem here is and how to fix this?

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged Symfony?

Comment: Can you show the parameters of `update()` and `validAvatar()`? It might be triggering [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)

Comment: By parameters do you mean the function parameters or the route parameters? Also, if this helps: I have now split up those two requests but I am facing the same issue. My validate and update function have their own FormRequest files but I have still the same error... But due to the split up there actually cannot be any triggering anymore...

Comment: I don't get why you do this kind of manual validation. As a user is authenticated, he should only be able to update Auth::user()->avatar(), so only its own avatar. Also, why do you use "name" instead of "ids" or "uuids", that would prevent characters or whitespace issues? Have you tried dump "^request->all()" in both cases to check that the issue does not comes from the submitted POST data?

Comment: I use the name because its my routing key. I want to show the route `user/[name]` to the user because this is way better then showing him his id. So the `name` is my routing key. To the other question: How else should I validate that the request I get to update the profile image is from the owner of the user image? Yes I have done that.. same problem.. very strange

Comment: I dump the `request->all` in the `authorize` method in both FormRequest classes because this is the first touch point of my request. In both cases I get for an empty array `[]` for `dd($this->request->all());`

Comment: What is `$this->user`? I don't think there is exist in original Form Request. Is that your input?

Comment: where is your controller method for this `user.avatar.valid` route? did you forget to typehint `User $user` in that controller method?

Comment: I believe you must do a $this->all() when inside the formRequest class. As @lagbox said, check your parameter type-hint in both methods. Or paste the code of both methods here.

Comment: @lagbox found the problem... I really forgot to pass the `User $user` to my controller as a parameter... Thank you so much.. I didn't found the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are typehinting the property in your controller's method signature properly for Route Model Binding. If not you will just get the value of the segment, the name of the user, instead of the User model since the Implicit Model Binding won't take place:

```
public function validAvatar(User $user) { ... }
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Route Model Bindings - Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding)

Comment: Sorry... I have no clue what you are talking about. To which part of the documentation are you referring? Where should I place this function?

Comment: that is your action for your `user.avatar.valid` method ... just showing the type hinting for the model binding which you are trying to use, as per your routes

Comment: Gotcha. But where do I have to place the `valid` function? Or do you mean this is my `function` to validate the avatar?

Comment: that is your controller method for your route `user.avatar.valid`  `UserController@validAvatar` ... I had the wrong name